# C++ calls Python, which then calls C++ again

Tags: python, c++, parameters, callback

Basically, it should look like this (in Pseudocode):

C++ file:

```
void do_stuff(){
  printf("Callback", );
}

void main(){
  call_python_function(&do_stuff);
}
```

Python file:

```
def python_function(ptr):
  ptr()
```

Just calling Python from C++ with some parameters is relatively easy, using Python.h, but how do I do the callback to C++? 
Also, I also want to pass around some data, so ideally, it should look something like this in the end:

C++ file:

```
vector<double> do_stuff(double a, double b){
  vector<double> v;
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) v.push_back(a*sin(b*i));
}

void main(){
  call_python_function(&do_stuff);
}
```

Python file:

```
def python_function(ptr):
  print ptr(1.2,3.4)
```

Is this possible somehow? I am considering using a message passing interface like ZeroMQ with some threading, but maybe there is a cleaner, and potentially simpler solution which looks more or less like what I have shown here?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using swig (http://www.swig.org/) to wrap the C++ functions which can be called from python script.

Comment: In the end I chose a different, conceptually more complicated, but easier to implement solution (the python function returns whenever it needs data from C++, and is then called again with the new data, so I only need the calling direction C++ -> Python). But, thanks anyway!